# With SVG Text font-size a little too small it blanks text; displayed text size does not change with font-size

Tags: svg, text, font-size

I am using SVG to map some lat-lons as polylines. This works. I now want to add some text at a proper scalable size.

This simplified sample should show three letters at different sizes.  Firefox shows only 2, each the same size.  Chrome, Opera, and Edge all show no letters.  There are some lines to show where the letters should be, so I know it is within the viewport.

Firefox does not display the center letter at any smaller value than the ".0084" for font-size. I have not found any value that works with the other browsers.

I have tried using units of "%", "px" and [none] to get "user coordinates."  No luck.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<svg viewBox="-77.48874 -43.03 .06 .06" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <text x="-77.50" y="-43.01447" font-size=".0084">X</text>
  <text x="-77.48" y="-43.01447" font-size=".0083">E</text>
  <text x="-77.46" y="-43.01447" font-size=".0200">S</text>

  <line x1="-77.48" y1="-43.01447" x2="-77.9" y2="-43.01447" 
    stroke-width="1%" stroke="#00ff00" />
  <line x1="-77.46" y1="-43.01447" x2="-77.46" y2="-43.81446" 
    stroke-width="1%" stroke="teal"/>
  <line x1="-77.48" y1="-43.01447" x2="-77.48" y2="-43.81446" 
    stroke-width="1%" stroke="teal"/>
  <line x1="-77.50" y1="-43.01447" x2="-77.50" y2="-43.81446" 
    stroke-width="1%" stroke="teal"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your SVG canvas is very very small (.06/.06). In your example the font is invisible. Please read this article about [The Limits of Numbers in SVG](https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/extras/ch08-precision.html)

Comment: Firefox's underlying unit are in 120ths of a point. Multiply 0.0084 x 120 and see. The answer is use a bigger font size in the first place. I.e. scale your whole drawing up.

Comment: Thank you, @enxaneta.  I also found this useful: [Understanding SVG Coordinate Systems and Transformations](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/) .  But, still, I can get large characters, but anything just a little smaller disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may have understood from the comments you need to increase the size of everything in your SVG. In the next example I've multiplied everything by 100. I had to change the x of the viewBox because otherwise the letter X would fall outside.

```html
<svg viewBox="-7750.5 -4303 6 6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <text x="-7750" y="-4301.447" font-size=".84">X</text>
  <text x="-7748." y="-4301.447" font-size=".83">E</text>
  <text x="-7746" y="-4301.447" font-size="2">S</text>

  <line x1="-7748" y1="-4301.447" x2="-7790" y2="-430144.7" 
    stroke-width="1%" stroke="#00ff00" />
  <line x1="-7746" y1="-4301.447" x2="-7746" y2="-4381.446" 
    stroke-width="1%" stroke="teal"/>
  <line x1="-7748" y1="-4301.447" x2="-7748" y2="-4381.446" 
    stroke-width="1%" stroke="teal"/>
  <line x1="-7750" y1="-4301.447" x2="-7750" y2="-4381.446" 
    stroke-width="1%" stroke="teal"/>
</svg>
```

**Please** do not use extremely small numbers.

Comment: Thank you @enxaneta.  That works.  I am actually specifying font-sizes in % to be sure I get proper scaling.  I need text about 2% or 3% of "normal size" in my application of a town park map.